# Remove currency symbol odoo 11

Tags: qweb, odoo-11

I changed thousands separator to ' instead of ,.
Now when I try to remove the currency symbol, the thousand separator also be removed.

I have tried those code:

```
<span t-field="l.price_subtotal" t-field-options="{'widget':'False'}"/>
```

and

```
<span t-field="l.price_subtotal"
      t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;False&quot;}"/>
```

Can you help me to display the price as 1'542 without currency

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try these

```
<span t-esc="'{:,.2f}'.format(l.price_subtotal)" >
```

Comment: Thanks,but I'd like to show the price 1'456.00 and not 1,456.00

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `<span t-esc="float(object.field_name)"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
<span t-field="l.price_subtotal" widget="monetary"/>
```